# 'Provide value on 'System.Windows.Baml2006.TypeConverterMarkupExtension' threw an exception.' Line number '49' and line position '38'

Tags: c#, wpf

I am making my first wpf application which now just implements a "floor" with a texture, viewed from above. when running I get this exception:

> Provide value on System.Windows.Baml2006.TypeConverterMarkupExtension' threw an exception.' Line number '49' and line position '38'

The line they talk about is

```
<ImageBrush ImageSource="/wood1_1000X1000.jpg" />.
```

I also tried with a png extension. The image has a resolution of 1000 x 1000.

Comment: What's the stack trace saying? any specific message in inner exception details.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Assuming the image is:

- Included in your project
- It's in a folder named "Images"
- The build action for the image is set to "Resource" (should be the default)

You can reference it like this:

```
<ImageBrush ImageSource=
   "pack://application:,,,/YourProjectName;component/Images/wood1_1000X1000.jpg";
```

Comment: This fixed the issue, I put the image in the project folder whithout including it in the project itself.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had foreground color as 282828 for a checkbox. I changed it as #282828. Its fixed the issue.