# WPF Canvas - background with both gradient and image?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, canvas, background

For the duration of my development of this application, I have been using a canvas for the rendering of 3D models. This canvas has, until now, been represented with this XAML:

```
<Canvas x:Name="modelCanvas" Grid.Row="0">
    <Canvas.Background>
        <RadialGradientBrush>
            <GradientStop Color="#FFDED9D9" Offset="1"/>
            <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.007"/>
        </RadialGradientBrush>
    </Canvas.Background>
</Canvas>
```

I would like to add an image to this background as well. I tried adding `<ImageBrush ImageSource="/Images/bg2.png"/>` as a child of `Canvas.Background`, but this obviously failed because only one brush can be used to set the background. Is there not some way of combining brushes? Could this responsibility instead fall on the Viewport? I was hoping to keep this image entirely separate from the rendering environment.

Although ideally the solution to this problem can be solved in XAML, I am developing the project in C# if it comes to that.

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to achieve. Is the image just a partly transparent overlay over the gradient, or do you probably want to have a gradient in the image opacity?

Comment: @Clemens The image is partially transparent and meant to be superimposed over the gradient. One obvious option is to just make such an image in an image editor, but I'd like to avoid that solution.

Comment: _"Is there not some way of combining brushes?"_ -- I'm not aware of a built-in "composite brush" type. However, you can use `DrawingBrush` to combine _drawing_ objects into a single brush that can be used as the background. You can use `DrawingGroup` to combine an `ImageDrawing` and a `GeometryDrawing`, the latter using your `RadialGradientBrush`. Set the `DrawingBrush.Drawing` to the `DrawingGroup` and voila, you've got a single brush you can use as the background. You can also use the answer Clemens posted. Either way, you'll need to make sure to include your image in the build.

Comment: @PeterDuniho This comes very close to working. I can get everything to look the way I want in the XAML preview on Visual Studio, but when I run the project I immediately experience [this error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22736582/provide-value-on-system-windows-baml2006-typeconvertermarkupextension-threw-a). I've isolated my `<ImageDrawing .../>` object as the reason for the error, but changing the path syntax as the linked answer suggests does not get rid of the error.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I believe you have successfully answered the question at hand, though, and that I should just submit a new question for this error.

Answer (score 0):

You could put the Canvas in a Grid, move the GradientBrush to the Grid's Background, and add an Image element as the first child of the Grid:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Background>
        <RadialGradientBrush>
            <GradientStop Color="#FFDED9D9" Offset="1"/>
            <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.007"/>
        </RadialGradientBrush>
    </Grid.Background>
    <Image Source="transparent.png"/>
    <Canvas x:Name="modelCanvas" Grid.Row="0">
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, while looking at the Visual Studio preview of this makes it appear working, as soon as I run the program (which initializes some lights in the canvas's viewport) the image is no longer visible. The gradient is visible, though.

Comment: Make sure the image file is part of your Visual Studio project and its Build Action is set to Resource.

Comment: I observed the exact same behavior (gradient but no image) after I made sure the image was part of the project and set as a Resource.

Comment: You did not by accident set any Background on the Canvas? It should be null or Transparent.

Comment: Yes, the Canvas line is simply `<Canvas x:Name="modelCanvas"/>` placed after the `<Grid.Background>` and `<Image>`.